# SQL to Linq Expression?

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

Does anyone know of a tool to take a T-SQL query and convert it into a LINQtoSQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the way LINQ handles joins, that is a non-trivial problem. I actually tried in the past, but I just couldn't get the semantics right.

(Maybe I will try again using OSLO and MGrammar. Having a decent replacement for LEX and YACC will go a long way.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry that I don't know of any tools to do this.  If your problem is that you just don't know Linq well enough, you may want to consider this [tool](http://www.linqpad.net).  It will help you learn Linq and it's free (but not open source).